# Getting filename and extension from friendly url in java

Tags: java, http, url

I'm writing a small java-program for downloading blacklists from the Internet. 
The URLs can be of two types: 
1) direct link, e.g: http://www.shallalist.de/Downloads/shallalist.tar.gz

 Absolutely no problem here, we can use some library, such as: `apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;` or simply look for the last occurrence of `"/"` and `"."`

2) "frienly url", which is something like: http://urlblacklist.com/cgi-bin/commercialdownload.pl?type=download&file=bigblacklist

 Here no explicit filename and extension is present, but if I use my browser or Internet Download Manager (IDM), filename+extension would be: `"bigblacklist.tar.gz"`

 How to solve this problem in java and get filenames and extensions from "friendly" URLs?

 P.S: I know about `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` fields, but the Response Header for the urlblacklist link is:

```
Transfer-Encoding : [chunked]
Keep-Alive : [timeout=5, max=100]
null : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Server : [Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)]
Connection : [Keep-Alive]
Date : [Sat, 05 Sep 2015 23:51:35 GMT]
Content-Type : [ application/octet-stream]
```

As we see, there's nothing connected with .gzip (.gz). How to deal with it using java?

 And how do web browsers and download managers recognize the correct name and extension? 

 ===============UPDATE===================== 
Thanks to @eugenioy, the problem was solved. The real trouble was in IP-blocking for my multiple downloading attempts, that's why I decided to use proxies. Now it looks like (for the both types of URL) :

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyIP, port));
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(downloadFrom).openConnection(proxy);
String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
if (disposition != null) {
// extracts file name from header field
    int index = disposition.indexOf("filename");
    if  (index > 0) {
        fullFileName = disposition.substring(disposition.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, disposition.length() );
    }
} else {
// extracts file name from URL
    fullFileName = downloadFrom.substring(downloadFrom.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, downloadFrom.length());
            }
```

Now `fullFileName` contains the name of the file to download + its extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the output from curl:

```
curl -s -D - 'http://urlblacklist.com/cgi-bin/commercialdownload.pl?type=download&file=bigblacklist' -o /dev/null
```

You will see this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 00:55:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Content-disposition: attachement; filename=bigblacklist.tar.gz
Content-length: 22840787
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I gues that's how the browsers get the filename and extension:

```
Content-disposition: attachement; filename=bigblacklist.tar.gz
```

Or to do it from Java:

```
    URL obj = new URL("http://urlblacklist.com/cgi-bin/commercialdownload.pl?type=download&file=bigblacklist");
    URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
    String disposition = conn.getHeaderField("Content-disposition");
    System.out.println(disposition);
```

**NOTE**: The servers seems to block your IP after trying several times, so make sure to try this from a "clean" IP if you already tried many times today.

Comment: thank you for you reply! The actual problem was in IP-blocking. That's why I decided to use proxies and now it works for me!